# how to cast a Dictionary<string, object> to a Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>>

Tags: c#, object, dictionary, casting

I dynamically created a `Dictionary<string,object>` and recursively assigned the object(dictionary's value) to either a `string` , `Dictionary<string,string>` or another `Dictionary<string,object>`. I have been able to write code to take out the information from the `string` levels but not when it is a `Dictionary<string,object>`.

I simply tried casting the value to a `Dictionary<string, string>` but an error is thrown saying the object cannot be casted to that.

I know for a fact that the underlying structure is a `Dictionary<string, string>`. How can I gather the information form the object.

Comment: You might know it for a fact, but your compiler doesn't. tell him (by casting).

Comment: @speising That'll just result in the program crashing at runtime.

Comment: @Servy why? if the object is actually a Dictionary<string, string>, casting should be valid. (note i'm talking about inside the foreach here)

Comment: @speising But that's not what the question is asking to do.  The question is asking how to cast the entire outer dictionary, to which you simply cannot.  The whole point is that he doesn't want to have to cast the value to its actual type every time he uses the dictionary.

Comment: @Servy it implicitly was, see the middle paragraph.

Comment: @speising Yes, now see the title, first, and third paragraphs.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create an entirely new dictionary of the type that you want, and cast the values of the old dictionary to their actual type before adding them to the new dictionary.  Of course, this doesn't actually take all that much *code*, because there are tools to obscure all of the work being done, but that work still needs to be done.

```
var newDictionary = oldDictionary.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key,
    pair => (Dictionary<string,string>)pair.Value);
```

Comment: So simple but a very good answer